# Semantic UI datepicker - format - dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: date, meteor, datepicker, semantic-ui

Cannot get Semantic UI datepicker in a Form to return date in format - dd/mm/yyyy
I am using Meteor.

```
 <div class="five wide required field">
     <label>Expiry Date</label>
     <input type="date" name="dateExpire" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value={{dateExpire}}>
 </div>
```

Comment: what errors are you getting ? do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't get an error, the datepicker always returns the date in the format mm/dd/yyyy.  Don't know how to jsfiddle a meteor example using semantic-ui

Answer (score 5):

I found this when I search for the same and it worked out.

```
var calendarOpts = {
    type: 'date',
    formatter: {
        date: function (date, settings) {
            if (!date) return '';
            var day = date.getDate() + '';
            if (day.length < 2) {
                day = '0' + day;
            }
            var month = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '';
            if (month.length < 2) {
                month = '0' + month;
            }
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
        }
    }
};

$('.ui.calendar').calendar(calendarOpts);
```

Answer (score 1):

`date` type input values will be returned as `YYYY-MM-DD` format regardless of their display format. You can then convert this into a date object and format it as you wish. The easiest way to do this is probably with the [`moment`](http://momentjs.com/docs/) JavaScript library.

```
moment(dateInputValue).format("DD/MM/YY");
```

Comment: It looks like semantic-ui must be already formatting the date as I always get the date in format mm/dd/yyyy returned